# How to understand by the structure of parquet files whether they are partitions or separate files

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, parquet, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have such folders/files structure in the ADLS gen2 container:

```
entity/year/month/day/
     _success
     _committed...
     _started...
     part-0000...snappy.parquet
     part-0001...snappy.parquet
     part-N...snappy.parquet
```

How can I understand from this if the files in the  folder are partitions of a single file, or they are separate files?

Or maybe all this folder structure with the files is a "single" parquet file but just partitioned?

I'm using Databricks to read the files.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely entity/year/month/day are partitions (unless you are managing them yourself) the files in that directory are saved by a spark executor "partition".  Each of them individually are useful but won't include entity/year/month/day columns (the directory is that information).

So, for example, you have run df.repartition(100).write and have only got data for a single day and entity you are saving, then you could expect to have around 100 files - file size allowing.  If you append more for that day you'll have more files.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below methods to identify those.

**Based on the part file names** (numbers), you can identify that there are multiple files(same dataframe or another dataframe with different schema) that are appended to this location.

I have partitioned my files like below.

```
df.write.partitionBy("Year", "Month", "Day").mode("overwrite").parquet("/mnt/data/entity/")
```

Here, for demo I have appended same dataframe one time to `/mnt/data/entity/`and different dataframe one time to this location `data/entity/Year=2019/Month=2/Day=1` .

[image]

You can see that files with same colour are from one append and others are from another append of the dataframe(Here we cannot say that the dataframe is same or different).

To identify that the dataframe appended is also different, **read the dataframe and you will get null values** when you have parquet files from different dataframe.

Here, the dataframe will read the schema from the first parquet file of that location.

[image]

To know the parquet file names and file paths while reading, use [`file-metadata-column`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/ingestion/file-metadata-column) and identify the different parquet files.

```
display(spark.read.parquet('/mnt/data/entity/').select("*", "_metadata.file_name","_metadata.file_path"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try a short script to analyze the schema of files.

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Parquetanalyzer").getOrCreate()

data = spark.read.parquet("adl://<storage_account_name>.dfs.core.windows.net/<container>/entity/year/month/day/")

data.printSchema()

data.show()
```

If each part-N...snappy.parquet file contains different data, then they are separate files. If they all contain the same schema and seem to hold different partitions of the same data based on the partitioning keys, then they are partitions of a single dataset.